# http error codes in gwt rpc

Tags: spring, http, gwt, http-status-codes, gwt-rpc

I am working with a web application which uses gwt, spring, hibernate. And I am using gwtrpcspring RemoteServiceDispatcher for remote service mapping. Currently if my application throws MyException from any method I want catch that and have to send some http error codes like 402. Based on the exception type error codes will change. I am planning to do this at generic level. Is there any way to achieve without help of spring AOP?

How to achieve this in gwt rpc/spring at higher level?

Answer (score 0):

A good generic way of approaching this problem is to define/subclass your "MyException" class, that represents the different error states.  Using RPC those can be sent to the client where you can do your processing.

Comment: Right. But in all the method's signature I have to add throws MyException. I am planning to avoid that.

Comment: If MyException is a checked exception then yes, but if you want to avoid adding all the throws clauses, you could make it a RuntimeException type instead.

Comment: In gwt we can not catch the RunTimeException in onFailure. It supports only CheckedException.